# internet explorer site compatibility

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a completed website. It doesn't show correctly on some IE versions. If I have to run it on IE I have to change all the style sheet and it will be a mess if I do that. What are my best options to get the site work on IE? Any suggestions? I know this question is poorly explained. But I want to get it work at least little by trial and error. So help would be really appreciated.

Comment: *Welcome to IE nightmare series*

Comment: Steps: 1. Define which IE version do you support; 2. Use proper DOCTYPE whenever possible; 3. Check IE compatibility of your CSS; 4. Give up supporting IE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some will recommend using the X-UA-Compatible META tag which allows you to define which version of IE rendering engine will be used for a page. I suppose you're going to pick the version that works well for your pages like the example below:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

But I would highly suggest otherwise and use the "edge mode" because it

> is the preferred document mode; it represents the highest support for
>   modern standards available to the browser.

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Sooner or later, you will have the same problem again and will have to deal with it since

> Starting with IE11, document modes are deprecated and should no longer
>   be used, except on a temporary basis. **Make sure to update sites that**
>   **rely on legacy features and document modes to reflect modern**
>   **standards**.

So make an additional investment of time to adjust your pages accordingly with the latest standards

More details can be found here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bg182625(v=vs.85).aspx#docmode

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325(v=vs.85).aspx

https://www.modern.ie/en-us/performance/how-to-use-x-ua-compatible